# Can a GA headset be used for listening to normal audio or with a cell phone?

Tags: passenger, headset

I own an older but still nice noise-cancelling general aviation headset from Denali, with the two-plug adapter.

I wonder if I can/shall repurpose it.  For example, I now have to take a number of international flights, 14 hours as a sardine...  not fun.  Does a GA headset make for a good entertainment and silence headset?  Or, I could use the GA headset for phone calls from my Android cell phone.

Good idea / bad idea?

Comment: I think 14 hours wearing the weight of a typical GA headset would be worse :-) This seems like it will be an opinion-based question, but I think a GA headset is just too heavy and bulky to be practical on long flights, it would be better to spend $50 (or whatever) on a small, light noise-cancelling set for travel.

Comment: In general, I think this would be opinion based, but the "use it as a headset for my phone" portion is answerable. In answer-ish - I believe there are adapters made.

Answer (score 2):

I actually know a guy that does this. He bought a nice noise canceling headset but then stopped flying and now he uses it on long flights and quite enjoys it. For what its worth noise canceling headphones have come down in price over the years and you may simply be able to sell the headset and buy a less bulky set of headphones for the money you make. But if you dont want to go through the hassle then there is nothing stopping you from using aside from having a boom mic dangling off it.

For what its worth a lot of noise canceling headphones now have mic inputs as well so you can answer calls from them as well.